# FullSimplify does not work on this expression with no unknowns

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I can't reproduce this simple example from Habrat, 2010 ("*Mathematica* : a Problem-Centered Approach"). It is supposed to demonstrate the functionality of `FullSimplify`, however I can't make it work in *Mathematica 9*. When I try this:

```
FullSimplify[ Cot[ (5 Pi)/22 ] + 4 Sin[ (2 Pi)/11 ]]
```

*Mathematica 9* returns the input unchanged:

```
Cot[ (5 Pi)/22 ] + 4 Sin[ (2 Pi)/11 ]
```

As shown in the book however, I would rather  have expected `Sqrt[11]`. On the other trying

```
FullSimplify[ Cot[ (5 Pi)/22 ] + 4 Sin[ (2 Pi)/11 ] == Sqrt[11] ]
```

*Mathematica 9* returns

```
True
```

so why not return `Sqrt[11]` in the first place?

Comment: `FullSimplify[Cot[(5 Pi)/22] + 4 Sin[(2 Pi)/11]]` returns `Sqrt[11]` in mathematica 8.0.4

Comment: Works if you use `TrigToExp` before `FullSimplify`. Maybe the order of simplifications changed slightly, but this is a general problem with `FullSimplify`--it only makes simplifications that reduce the complexity of the expression, so if a step is needed that produces a much larger intermediate, this path will not be pursued.

Comment: @OleksandrR. thanks, that works! Seems like FullSimplify is both powerful and finicky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before `Mathematica 9` `FullSimplify[ Cot[ (5 Pi)/22 ] + 4 Sin[ (2 Pi)/11 ]]` yielded simply `Sqrt[11]` while in the newest version we should play a bit with `ComplexityFunction`. For some reason the `ComplexityFunction` behavior in `FullSimplify` has been changed. One can guess that it is just a different gauge of this option. To shed light on this issue let's define the following function :

```
cfs[n_][e_] :=  n Count[e, _Sin, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
```

After playing a bit  we can figure out the threshold values :

```
FullSimplify[ Cot[(5 Pi)/22] + 4 Sin[(2 Pi)/11], ComplexityFunction -> #] & /@ {
                  cfs[5], cfs[6], cfs[37], cfs[38] } // Column
```

[image]

In `Mathematica 8` and earlier all these complexity functions yield `Sqrt[11]`. We could find this threshold therein :

```
FullSimplify[Cot[(5 Pi)/22] + 4 Sin[(2 Pi)/11], ComplexityFunction -> #] & /@ {
                  cfs[-10], cfs[-9]} // Column
```

[image]

I.e. we have a direct jump between the final results in earlier versions while in `ver.9` there are intermediate values where `cfs` provided an intermediate result. So in the newer version `ComplexityFunction` is more customizable and therfore it is advantageous.

Another possibility in `ver. 9` to get `Sqrt[11]`  might be e.g. :

```
FullSimplify[ Cot[(5 Pi)/22] + 4 Sin[(2 Pi)/11], TransformationFunctions -> RootReduce]
```

Comment: great answer, thanks. If the default ComplexityFunction has not changed, I guess the difference in `Mathematica 9` is in the order in which `FullSimplify` attempts various simplification methods?

Comment: @Jerome I think that now `ComplexityFunction` is more powerful even though it might be more difficult to get desired results in special cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
TrigExpand[Cot[(5 Pi)/22] + 4 Sin[(2 Pi)/11]] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: thanks, that works, but TrigExpand alone seems to do the job as suggested by OleksandrR. in the OP. Can you simplify your answer?

Comment: Thanks, didn't think of trying without.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RootReduce[Cot[(5 π)/22] + 4 Sin[(2 π)/11]]
```

or

```
MinimalPolynomial[Cot[(5 π)/22] + 4 Sin[(2 π)/11]]
```