# Can't simplify Abs[a*Cos[x]]^2

Tags: simplifying-expressions, version-8, assumptions

Why doesn't

```
FullSimplify[ Abs[a*Cos[x]]^2, Assumptions -> {{a, x} ∈ Reals}]
```

simplify to

```
(a*Cos[x])^2
```

but this query

```
Simplify[ (a*Cos[x])^2 == Abs[a*Cos[x]]^2, Assumptions -> {{a, x} ∈ Reals}]
```

yields True?
I'm using *Mathematica 8.0*.

Comment: The expression with `Abs` is considered simpler: `LeafCount /@ {Abs[a Cos[x]]^2, (a*Cos[x])^2}` Have a look at the `ComplexityFunction` option for Simplify. (This is not posted as an answer because I think it is a duplicate question)

Comment: Thanks to both! I would have never figured that out!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We need an appropriate complexity function. There were a few questions on this topic but  in general, it is not obvious how to design an adequate function and it may appear quite difficult. Moreover there have been certain hidden changes of `ComplexityFunction` in  *Mathematica 9*  (see: [FullSimplify does not work on this expression with no unknowns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns).
By default we have:

```
OptionValue[ FullSimplify, ComplexityFunction]
```

> ```
> Automatic
> ```

It is not just the `LeafCount` function, nevertheless we could regard it as close to `LeafCount`.

```
LeafCount /@ {Abs[a Cos[x]]^2, a^2 Cos[x]^2, (a Cos[x])^2}
```

> ```
> {7, 8, 8}
> ```

Now the problem at hand is choosing a good candidate for `ComplexityFunction`, but since the given expression is quite simple, we can choose e.g.:

```
cf[k_][e_] := k Count[e, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e]
```

Now, `FullSimplify` as well as `Simplify` yield in `ver.8` (similarly in `ver. 9`):

```
FullSimplify[ Abs[ a Cos[x]]^2, Assumptions -> {(a | x) ∈ Reals},
              ComplexityFunction -> #]& /@ { cf[1], cf[2]}
```

> ```
> { Abs[a Cos[x]]^2, a^2 Cos[x]^2}
> ```

We can see that `cf[2]` appears to be sufficient to perform the desired simplification.

**Warning**

One should be careful since `ComplexityFunction` works a bit differently in *Mathematica 9*. The linked [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns/18875#18875) points out quite straightforward differences between  the recent versions of the system.