# How to automatically get rid of trig functions in an expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, trigonometry

I have a large expression containing many terms like this:

```
Sin[1/2 ArcTan[(2 Log[5])/(Log[5]^2 - 2)]]
```

[image: Sin[1/2 ArcTan[(2 Log[5])/(Log[5]^2 - 2)]]]

where a trig function is invoked on a rational multiple of an inverse trig function.

I want to expand trig functions such that this term turns into:

```
Sqrt[1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - (4 Log[5]^2)/(4 + Log[5]^4)])]
```

[image: Sqrt[1/2 (1 - Sqrt[1 - (4 Log[5]^2)/(4 + Log[5]^4)])]]

It is tedious to manually convert all such terms, so I am looking for a function that is able to do this automatically. Could you help me with it?

Comment: Closely related: [Can't simplify Abs(a*Cos@x)^2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32038/cant-simplify-absacosx2)  and [FullSimplify does not work on this expression with no unknowns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one

```
Sin[1/2 ArcTan[(2 Log[5])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)]] // FunctionExpand
```

[image]

Another approach is to apply your own rules. You just need to get rid of the rational between the trig function and the inverse trig function. For example

```
Sin[1/2 ArcTan[(2 Log[5])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)]] /. 
   Sin[1/2 x_] :> Sqrt[1/2 (1 - Cos[x])] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Verification

```
% // N
Sin[1/2 ArcTan[(2 Log[5])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)]] // N
```

> 0.640166
>
> 0.640166

Answer (score 7):

You can use `FullSimplify` and play with the `ComplexityFunction` `Option` until you obtain a satisfactory result. For example: Let's define our function in terms of `LeafCount`

```
 c[n_][e_] := n Count[e, _Sin | _ArcTan, Infinity] + LeafCount[e]
```

Then:

```
FullSimplify[Sin[1/2 ArcTan[(2 Log[5])/(Log[5]^2 - 2)]], 
   ComplexityFunction -> c[#]] & /@ Range[40, 60, 4]
```

Which gives:

> {I Sinh[1/4 (Log[1 - (I Log[25])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)] - 
>        Log[1 + (I Log[25])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)])],
>
> I Sinh[1/4 (Log[1 - (I Log[25])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)] - 
>        Log[1 + (I Log[25])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)])],
>
> I Sinh[1/4 (Log[1 - (I Log[25])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)] - 
>        Log[1 + (I Log[25])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)])],
>
> I Sinh[1/4 (Log[1 - (I Log[25])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)] - 
>        Log[1 + (I Log[25])/(-2 + Log[5]^2)])],
>
> Log[5] Sqrt[2/(  4 + Log[5]^4 - 2 Sqrt[4 + Log[5]^4] + Log[5]^2 Sqrt[4
>   + Log[5]^4])],
>
> Log[5] Sqrt[2/(   4 + Log[5]^4 - 2 Sqrt[4 + Log[5]^4] + Log[5]^2
>   Sqrt[4 + Log[5]^4])]}

Where the last 2 answers are the same as that obtained from `FunctionExpand`. Only this one is more flexible.