# Simplifying trig expressions containing Sqrt or Abs

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

The following Maple code can simplify `abs(sin(x))` into `-sin(x)` given the condition `-3Pi/4 < x < -Pi/2`

```maple
simplify(abs(sin(x))) assuming -3*Pi < x, x < -5*Pi/2;
```

I tried what I thought would be the equivalent *Mathematica* code:

```mma
FullSimplify[Abs[Sin[x]], Assumptions -> -3 Pi/4 < x < -Pi/2]
```

but *Mathematica*  does not give the answer I expected.

Another related  example.

Starting with `Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]] + Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]]` and the condition `-2Pi < x < -3Pi/2`, I want to get `-2 Cos[x/2]`, Here are some of things I tried:

```mma
Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]] + Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]] /. Sqrt[x_] :> Sqrt[TrigFactor[x]]
Refine[%, Assumptions -> -2 Pi < x < -3 Pi/2]
FullSimplify[%, Assumptions -> -2 Pi < x < -3 Pi/2]
```

Comment: Note that *Mathematica* considers `Abs[Sin[x]]` to be simpler than `Times[-1, Sin[x]]` (see e.g. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44931/why-doesnt-abs-simplify-further) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32038/cant-simplify-absacosx2)). That aside, there does seem to be a problem with simplifying the sign of trig functions. Compare `Simplify[Sign[Sin[x]], 0 < x < Pi]` and `Simplify[Sign[Sin[x]], -Pi < x < 0]`

Comment: However, `f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Abs | _Sqrt, {0, Infinity}] + LeafCount[e];
FullSimplify[Abs[Sin[x]], -3 Pi/4 < x < -Pi/2, 
 ComplexityFunction -> f]` doesn't seem to work either. Did I miss anything?

Comment: If I use `ComplexityFunction` to forbid `Abs`, the result is `Sqrt[Sin[x]^2]`. If further forbid `Power`, the result is a piecewise function. If further forbid `Piecewise`, the result returns to `Abs[Sin[x]]`. So it appears like it's not a complexity function problem.

Comment: @SimonWoods : Furthermore, `FullSimplify[Abs[Sin[x]] == -Sin[x], Assumptions -> -3 Pi/4 < x < -Pi/2]` does not simplify it either. Thus this should not be a complexity function issue.

Comment: @YiWang, I agree this is not a complexity function issue - I just wanted to point out that the first example would not "simplify" to the desired result even if *Mathematica* handled the assumptions properly.

Comment: @SimonWoods : Sorry I only read the first sentence of your original comment, not the second sentence :) Nevertheless my comments explain explicitly your second sentence in that comment.

Answer (score 1):

To address your first question, this:

```
    Simplify[Abs[Sin[x]], Assumptions -> {x >= \[Pi], x < 2 \[Pi]}, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (StringLength[ToString[#]] &)]

(*    -Sin[x]    *)
```

does the job. It is just since

```
StringLength[ToString[#]] &[Abs[Sin[x]]]
(*  11  *)

StringLength[ToString[#]] &[-Sin[x]]
(*   7   *)
```

It is more difficult with your second question. This is your initial expression

```
expr1 = Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]] + Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]];
```

Here we transform the terms under the radicals:

```
 expr2 = MapAt[TrigFactor, expr1, {{1, 1}, {2, 1}}]
(*   Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sin[\[Pi]/4 - x/2]^2] + 
 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[Sin[\[Pi]/4 + x/2]^2]   *)
```

Now let us introduce a complexity function:

```
 Clear[cf];
cf[e_] := (Count[e, _Abs, Infinity]);
```

and try to simplify each radical separately:

```
    expr3 = MapAt[
  Simplify[#, -2 \[Pi] < x < -3 \[Pi]/2, ComplexityFunction -> cf] &, 
  expr2, {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}]
```

The outcome is strange:

```
(*      Sqrt[2] Abs[Sin[\[Pi]/4 + x/2]] - Sqrt[2] Sin[\[Pi]/4 - x/2]     *)
```

The Abs is removed in one case, but did not disappear in the other. It is even more strange taking into account that `Sin[\[Pi]/4 + x/2]` in the interval in question is strictly negative. One can make sure of this by plotting it:

```
 Plot[{Sin[\[Pi]/4 + x/2], 
  Abs[Sin[\[Pi]/4 + x/2]]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], -3 \[Pi]/2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.005]}, {Red, Thickness[0.005]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {-1.2, 1.2}]
```

[image] Here `Sin[\[Pi]/4 + x/2]`is shown in blue and `Abs[Sin[\[Pi]/4 + x/2]]`- in red. 
 It is not clear what this complexity function does at all, since evaluation of this:

```
    cf[Abs[Sin[\[Pi]/4 + x/2]]]
cf[Abs[Sin[\[Pi]/4 - x/2]]]
```

returns 0 in both cases. However, it works in the one case in the expression above.  I do not understand it, and would be grateful for explanations.

Nevertheless, this operation did not work as expected, but we know what it should have done, let us make a substitution:

```
  expr4 = expr3 /. Abs[a_] -> -a // Simplify

(*    -2 Cos[x/2]     *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously what a person thinks is simplified and what a given CAS thinks is simplified will not always be the same.  This probably happens more often with functions like the trigonometric functions that admit so many identities.  Often it does not matter that much, but when it does, a certain amount of personal intervention may be required.

One hump to get over in the first example `Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]] + Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]]` is that the expression has to go through several transformations before it gets simpler (according to *Mathematica's* measure of simple).

Another is simplifying the `Piecewise` expansion of `Abs`, which I (have to?) do using the same `Solve` method of [chyaong](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2090/chyaong)

Finally, we can construct a complexity function that "has it in" for `Abs`, so that expressions without `Abs` tend to be selected.

Here are transformation functions for getting over the first two humps:

```
trigXFns = Sequence[
   Replace[#,
     e1_Piecewise :> 
      Module[{y}, 
       Replace[y /. First@Solve[y == e1 && $Assumptions], 
        e2_ConditionalExpression :> Simplify[e2]]
       ]] &,
   Composition[Simplify, ExpToTrig, Factor, PowerExpand, Factor, 
    TrigToExp]
   ];
```

Here is a simple way to avoid `Abs` when possible.  The coefficient in front of `Count` controls how strongly to try to eliminate `Abs`.

```
LeafCount[#] + 20 Count[#, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] &
```

There is yet another issue in the OP's examples, namely, assumptions.  The assumptions need to be passed to the transformation functions.  This does not happen with the `Assumptions` option to `Simplify`.  Therefore, we have to use `Assuming` (or `Block[{$Assumptions = ...`).

```
Assuming[-3 Pi/4 < x < -Pi/2,
 Simplify[Abs[Sin[x]],
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, trigXFns},
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 20 Count[#, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] &)]
 ]
(* -Sin[x] *)

Assuming[-2 Pi < x < -3 Pi/2,
 Simplify[Sqrt[1 - Sin[x]] + Sqrt[1 + Sin[x]],
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, trigXFns},
  ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 20 Count[#, _Abs, {0, Infinity}] &)]
 ]
(* 2 Cos[x/2] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Solve[{y==Sign[#]#&[Sin[x]],-3 Pi/4<x<-Pi/2},{y}]
Solve[{y==PiecewiseExpand[Abs@Sin[x],Reals],-3 Pi/4<x<-Pi/2},y]

Simplify[PiecewiseExpand[Abs@Sin@x,Reals],TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,Reduce[#&&-3Pi/4<x<-Pi/2,x]&}]
```