# Possible bug involving square roots simplifications?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following code:

```
1/2 (Sqrt[(-4 + x1) x1] + Sqrt[-4 + x1] Sqrt[x1]) //Simplify[#, {x1 < 0, (-4 + x1) < 0}] &

Sqrt[x] Sqrt[ y] + Sqrt[x y] // Simplify[#, {x < 0, y < 0}] &
```

which give respectively

```
1/2 (Sqrt[-4 + x1] Sqrt[x1] + Sqrt[(-4 + x1) x1])
```

and

```
0
```

Why in one case mathematica recognise a simplification and in the other not?

Comment: Seems to be an issue of the default `ComplexityFunction` giving too high complexities for the intermediate expressions in the first case. You can use e.g. `ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, Power[_, 1/2], All] &)` to devalue square roots, which makes `Simplify` return `0` in both examples. You can also use `ComplexityFunction -> (100 Count[#, Power[_, 1/2], All] + LeafCount[#] &) as a more general complexity function that just gives a high penalty to square roots.

Comment: Related: [Can't simplify Abs\[a*Cos\[x\]\]^2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32038/cant-simplify-absacosx2)