# How can I simplify $\log(512)$ to $9\log(2)$?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

Can you explain me about the result of `Integrate`.

```
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(1\), \(3\)]\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), 
    \(1\), \(3\)]\*FractionBox[\(9  v\), \(v + u\ v\)] \[DifferentialD]u \[DifferentialD]v\)\)
(*
    2 log(512)
*)

% // Simplify
(*
    2 log(512)
*)

% // FullSimplify
(*
    18 log(2)
*)
```

However, I cannot FullSimplify this result

```
FullSimplify[Log[512]]
(*
    log(512)
*)

Log[512] // N
(*
    6.23832
*)

FullSimplify[2 Log[512]] // N
(*
    12.4766
*)
```

So question $1$ is how to simplify `Log[512]` and why it doesn't simplify to `9Log[2]` by default.

```
9 Log[2] // N
(*
    6.23832
*)
```

When I'm integrating by hand, I collect `9` or `18` easily, so I like the result `18 log(2)` , not `2 log(512)`, so I wonder why  *Mathematica*  gives this result?

Answer (score 12):

*Mathematica* does not consider `9 Log[2]` to be "simpler" than `Log[512]`.  The full default [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) is not disclosed (the one in the documentation is not entirely equivalent IIRC), but a good first-order approximation is often [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeafCount.html)

```
LeafCount /@ {Log[512], 9 Log[2]}
```

> ```
> {2, 4}
> ```

If you provide a `ComplexityFunction` that uses a different metric by which `9 Log[2]` has a lower score than `Log[512]`, such as the largest integer that appears in the expression, it will reduce as you desire:

```
FullSimplify[Log[512], ComplexityFunction -> (Max @ Cases[#, _Integer, {0, -1}] &)]
```

> ```
> 9 Log[2]
> ```

Answer (score 9):

This kind of transformation `Log[512] -> 9 Log[2]` is not a simplification of the underlying expression but rather expanding it, there is `PowerExpand` which appears to be the simplest approach:

```
PowerExpand @ Log @ 512
```

> ```
> 9 Log[2]
> ```

We can see that `Log[512]` is simpler than `9 Log[2]`, to demonstrate it we can use `TreeForm`:

```
GraphicsRow[ TreeForm /@ {9 Log[2], Log[512]}]
```

[image]

When we are trying to transform adequate expressions with `FullSimplify` `LeafCount`  only approximates  `ComplexityFunction`, however in general it can't explain specific simplifications. Moreover `ComplexityFunction` works in a different way in *Mathematica 9* in comparison to earlier versions, see e.g. [FullSimplify does not work on this expression with no unknowns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns/18875#18875) discussing how one can deal with similar problems.
Having said that I find simpler using the `TransformationsFunctions` option of `FullSimplify` rather than searching for appropriate `ComplexityFunction`, namely here we would use `PowerExpand`:

```
FullSimplify[ Log[512], TransformationFunctions -> PowerExpand]
```

> ```
> 9 Log[2]
> ```

Now `FullSimlify` uses **only** `PowerExpand` while (see the documentation):

> `TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic,` $f_1$, $f_2$, $\ldots$ `}` uses built-in transformation functions together with the functions $f_i$.

Comment: Artes, congratulations on the Steward badge.  That's a lot of reviewing.  Thank you!