# Simplifying just parts of an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm having trouble with the simplifications of certain expressions.
A typical example of this is the following (all my variables are positive real numbers):

```
k1 = Exp[-t1/al];
et2 = 1 + Exp[-t6/al];
xi2 = 1 + Exp[-t6/al] + Exp[-(t4 + t6)/al];
Log[k1] Log[et2/xi2]
```

This produces

$$ \log\left(e^{-t1/\alpha}\right) \log\left(\dfrac{1+e^{-t6/\alpha}}{1+e^{-(t4+t6)/\alpha} + e^{-t6/\alpha}}\right)$$

Now, I want to get rid of that trivial $\log(\exp)$, so I used `Simplify`

```
Simplify[%, Element[{t1, t4, t6, al}, Reals] && al != 0]
```

which gives

$$ -\dfrac{t1}{\alpha}\log\left(\dfrac{e^{t4/\alpha}(1+e^{t6/\alpha})}{
   1 + e^{t4/\alpha}+e^{(t4 + t6)/\alpha}}\right)$$

This is right, of course, but unfortunately it produces an undesired effect: inside the second logarithm, Mathematica has factored $e^{-t4/\alpha}$ and $e^{-(t4+t6)/\alpha}$, turning negative powers in positive ones.
At the end of the day, I will let $\alpha\to0$, so really I'm more comfortable with negative powers of $e$ (it is apparent which terms will be negligible in the limit).

**How can I tell Mathematica not to touch the argument of the second logarithm?**

Comment: If You want `Simplify` to simplify only the first part (first logarithm) You can try `Simplify[%[[1]], Element[{t1, t4, t6, al}, Reals] && al != 0]*%[[2]]`.

Comment: Yeah, that could work just fine. The example above is just a single term in a sum of five pieces, each one of which gives the same problem, but I could always select the various contributions with [[...]].

Comment: You might find helpful `PowerExpand`, see e.g. here [How can I simplify log(512) to 9log(2)?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39351/how-can-i-simplify-log512-to-9-log2/39356#39356)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general one can use MapAt to apply the operator to the specified part of expression. In your case, however, this

```
  Log[E^(-(t1/al))] Log[(1 + E^(-(t6/al)))/(
   1 + E^((-t4 - t6)/al) + E^(-(t6/al)))] /. Log[Exp[Z_]] -> Z

(* -((t1 Log[(1 + E^(-(t6/al)))/(
   1 + E^((-t4 - t6)/al) + E^(-(t6/al)))])/al) *)
```

is simpler.

Answer (score 6):

As Alexei Boulbitch said, you can use `MapAt` to direct `Simplify` to the desired subexpression.  This always requires some extra mental effort though to figure out what is the index of the part you are interested in. It is sometimes more practical to just select the subexpression you want changed and use the Algebraic Manipulation palette, which you will find in the Palettes menu.

It's convenient to use the `$Assumptions` variable to set up the assumptions permanently, as you can't specify any when you use the palette.

[image]

Just use the mouse to select the subexpression you wish to simplify and click the Simplify button.  The subexpression will be replaced with the simplified version.

Answer (score 4):

`Refine` seems more appropriate than `Simplify`. Replacing your `Simplify` with `Refine` seems to deliver the result you want

```
Refine[Log[k1] Log[et2/xi2], Element[{t1, t4, t6, al}, Reals] && al != 0]
```

`Refine` just tries to apply the assumptions without transforming the expression too much. There are no guarantees, and a manual approach may be necessary, but at least in this case it seems to work

Comment: A strange thing: this: Simplify[Log[E^(-(t1/al))], Element[{t1, al}, Reals] && al != 0] yields a right answer. The same with Refine. And this: Simplify[Log[E^(-(t1/al))], {t1 \[Element] Reals, 
  a1 \[Element] Reals && al != 0}] does not both for the Simplify and for Refine. But these two formulations are equally legal. Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I think the assumptions should be combined with logical operations, and not as a list. Try joining them with &&

Comment: No this: Simplify[Log[E^(-(t1/al))], {t1 \[Element] Reals && a1 \[Element] Reals &&al != 0}] does not work either. Besides, in all other cases Simplify perfectly works when the assumptions are separated by the mere comma.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I hope it's not because you are using `a1` in one place and `al` on the other?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I mixed a1 with al, but no, it does not work after correction of this mistake.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch It does work for me. Try this `Simplify[Log[
  E^(-(t1/al))], {t1 \[Element] Reals && al \[Element] Reals && al != 0}]`  Perhaps it's the bar before [Element]?

Comment: Probably I am getting crazy, you are right!

Answer (score 3):

For your specific question, if you just want to use `Simplify` the way you did here, another route is to `Hold` the part of the expression you don't wish to alter:

```
Simplify[Log[E^(-(t1/al))] Hold[Log[(1 + E^(-(t6/al)))/(1 + E^((-t4 - t6)/al) + E^(-(t6/al)))]], 
  Element[{t1, t4, t6, al}, Reals] && al != 0] // ReleaseHold
```