# Remove conditional for ThreeJSymbol

Tags: simplifying-expressions, conditional

When I evaluate:

```
Assuming[3 > jj >= 1 && jj \[Element] Integers, 
 ThreeJSymbol[{jj, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}]]
```

it outputs an expression saying that if

$3 > jj \ge 1$

I get a nonzero answer, otherwise it's zero. How do I remove this conditional? I found that Simplify does the trick, but this expression appears in a much bigger expression that I don't want to Simplify, because it will take forever. Is there a quick way to remove the conditional?

Comment: The `Simplify` should be placed within the scope of the `Assuming`, i.e., `Assuming[3 > jj >= 1 && jj \[Element] Integers, ThreeJSymbol[{jj, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}] // Simplify]` You can use parentheses to restrict the scope of the `Simplify`

Comment: Hi, I think you need to provide mory information, otherwise one has to guess what your actual expressions look like and how they were generated. You could try `yourExpression /. {f_Piecewise :> Simplify[f,Assumptions -> yourAssumptions]}`.

Comment: Here is a [related post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/simplifying-just-parts-of-an-expression).

Answer (score 1):

Does this meet your needs?

```
expr = ThreeJSymbol[{jj, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}];
Extract[expr, {1, 1, 1}]
expr[[1, 1, 1]]
```

[image]