# Cancellation of common terms

Tags: bugs, simplifying-expressions

Can someone explain why the term A in case 2 does not get canceled out when case 1 does? 
I use "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"

```
case1 = A*(E^(-λ) + α) == A;
Simplify[case1, A > 0]
```

gives `1 + E^λ α == E^λ`

```
case2 = A*(E^(-2*λ) + α) == A;
Simplify[case2, A > 0]
```

gives `A (E^(-2 λ) + α) == A`

Comment: I get `E^(-2*λ) + α == 1` for `case2` in version 7.  Perhaps try `FullSimplify`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard And also in version 8.  But not in version 9!  Moreover, `case1` is pretty weird too because `E^-\[Lambda] + \[Alpha] == 1` (what v8 returns) is clearly simpler than `1 + E^λ α == E^λ` (what v9 returns).  A v9 bug perhaps?  user11946: you can consider reporting this to support at wolfram.com since it seems that both results you mention are worse than what v8 (or v7) gives.

Comment: I tried. FullSimplify does not do it in version 9.0.0.1

Comment: @user11946 Why don't you write to support about this problem and report back here with what they told you?

Comment: Yes, I will report it to Wolfram.

Comment: This has been observed a year ago in another question: [FullSimplify does not work on this expression with no unknowns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns). There is an [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns/18875#18875) explaining how you can get what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Below is the email response from *Wolfram* support.

> Thank you for your email.
>   It is not clear to me why *Mathematica's* behavior has changed between version *8* and *9* in this example with *Simplify*.  As such, I have filed a report with our developers so that they can be aware of this behavior and make any changes as needed for future versions of Mathematica.  In the meantime, I will also be sure to pass on any useful information that I get from our developers.
>   Please let me know if you have any further questions.
>
> Karl Isensee
>
> Technical Support
>   *Wolfram Research, Inc.*

Comment: See this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns/18875#18875) to get an insight how to proceed.