# Why does Mathematica not simplify this expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider this simple example:

```
mytrans[expr_] := 
 expr /. Ω1^2 + Δ^2 :> Ω^2

f = 
  FullSimplify[Sqrt[-Δ^2 - Ω1^2], 
   TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, mytrans}, Assumptions -> #] &;

f /@ {{Δ > 0, Ω1 > 0, Ω > 0}, 
     {Δ > 0, Ω1 < 0, Ω > 0}, 
     {Δ < 0, Ω1 > 0, Ω > 0}, 
     {Δ < 0, Ω1 < 0, Ω > 0},
     {Δ ∈ Reals, Ω1 ∈ Reals, Ω > 0}}


(* {I Ω, I Ω, I Ω, I Ω, Sqrt[-Δ^2 - Ω1^2]} *)
```

Isn't the last assumption equivalent to the first four? Why doesn't it work? Or why does it work in the first four cases?

Comment: strange, because under MMA7 it works without modification

Comment: There are similar problems where earlier versions of _Mathematica_ worked expectedly while newer did not. See e.g. this answer [FullSimplify does not work on this expression with no unknowns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns/18875#18875).

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, let's see this case:

```
In[45]:= (FullSimplify[Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2], 
    Assumptions -> #] &) /@ {{a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}, {a > 0, b < 0, 
   c > 0}, {a < 0, b > 0, c > 0}, {a < 0, b < 0, 
   c > 0}, {a ∈ Reals, b ∈ Reals, c > 0}}

Out[45]= {I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], 
 I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2]}
```

In the last assumption, $\sqrt{-a^2-b^2}$ isn't simplified. It seems that for some unknown reasons, `FullSimplify` doesn't work in this case, though `Resolve` can give the correct answer.

```
In[76]:= FullSimplify[Sqrt[-(a^2 + b^2)] == I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2], 
 Assumptions -> {a, b} ∈ Reals]

Out[76]= Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2] == I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]

In[77]:= Resolve[
 ForAll[{a, b}, {a, b} ∈ Reals, 
  Sqrt[-a^2 - b^2] == I Sqrt[a^2 + b^2]]]

Out[77]= True
```

Then let's see this

```
In[88]:= Sqrt[-a-b]/.a+b:>c
Out[88]= Sqrt[-a-b]
In[89]:= HoldForm[Sqrt[-a-b]/.a+b:>c]//FullForm
Out[89]//FullForm= HoldForm[ReplaceAll[Power[Plus[Times[-1,a],Times[-1,b]],Rational[1,2]],RuleDelayed[Plus[a,b],c]]]
```

The FullForm shows that  $\sqrt{-a-b}$ is Plus[Times[-1,a],Times[-1,b]], while $\sqrt{a+b}$ is Plus[a,b], they don't match, so the `ReplaceAll` doesn't work

To avoid this case, we can use `a->c-b` as the rule, and it will be OK

```
In[81]:= Sqrt[-a - b] /. a :> c - b

Out[81]= Sqrt[-c]
```

Now we can return you problem, change `mytrans` in this way, and the answer will be correct

```
mytrans[expr_] := 
 expr /. Ω1^2 :> Ω^2 - Δ^2

f = 
  FullSimplify[Sqrt[-Δ^2 - Ω1^2], 
   TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, mytrans}, Assumptions -> #] &;

f /@ {{Δ > 0, Ω1 > 0, Ω > 0}, 
     {Δ > 0, Ω1 < 0, Ω > 0}, 
     {Δ < 0, Ω1 > 0, Ω > 0}, 
     {Δ < 0, Ω1 < 0, Ω > 0},
     {Δ ∈ Reals, Ω1 ∈ Reals, Ω > 0}}

(* {I Ω, I Ω, I Ω, I Ω, I Ω} *)
```

Comment: Why does it work if we have assumptions like a>0 b>0? For example, this works:`mytrans[expr_] := expr /. a + b :> c
FullSimplify[Sqrt[-a - b], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, mytrans}, 
 Assumptions -> {c > 0, a > 0, b > 0}]`

Comment: Because `FullSimplify[Sqrt[-a - b], Assumptions -> { a > 0, b > 0}]` give the result $i \sqrt{a+b}$, so mytrans can work. But I don't know why it will give different result with  `Assumptions -> {a, b} ∈ Reals`, even `Assumptions -> {a >=0 , b>= 0}` can't give  $i \sqrt{a+b}$. That really confuse me a lont