# Display trigonometry without Csc and Cot

Tags: trigonometry

I have a result with trigonometry functions using Cot and Csc.
I would like to keep only cos, sin and tan and so prefer fractions in the display of the results.
**How is it possible to ask Mathematica for not using Cot, Csh ... ?**

Thank you for your help

Comment: Here is a recent question [Evaluating complicated trig without resorting to numerical methods](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75326/evaluating-complicated-trig-without-resorting-to-numerical-methods) helpful in general cases such as your question. If you can't make use of that you have to be more specific with your problem.

Comment: see this answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7800/19476

Answer (score 0):

I would define it as follows.

```
 f[x_] := (E^(3 x + 2))HoldForm[(1/Sin[2*x])]
```

If you type in f[x] , it returns e^(3x+2) (1/Sin[2x])

In order to evaluate it at any time,

```
  ReleaseHold[ f[x]] /. x -> Pi/4
```