# Substitution in trigonometric expressions to remove secant and cosecant functions

Tags: replacement, trigonometry

I manipulate equations which are trigonometric equations in mechanics. In theses equations, the custom is to use only Cos, Sin and Tan functions and not the secant and cosecant functions.

To prevent Mathematica’s use of these functions, I found this code in this forum:

```
$PrePrint = # /. {Csc[z_] :> 1/Defer@Sin[z],
                  Sec[z_] :> 1/Defer@Cos[z],
                  Cot[z_] :> Defer@Cos[z]/Defer@Sin[z]} &;
```

This code worked well until now.

But, at the moment, I need to made some substitutions in a expression and I can’t make it work.

Here the two rules that I want to use in my substitutions:

```
RègleCΦ = (Cos[Φ] -> Cos[η2] Cos[ψ2] + Sin[η2] Sin[θ2] Sin[ψ2])

RègleSΦ = (Sin[Φ] -> (-Cos[ψ2] Sin[η2] Sin[θ2] + Cos[η2] Sin[ψ2])/(Cos[η2] Cos[θ2] Cos[ϕ2] - Sin[θ2] Sin[ϕ2]))
```

Here is the equation where I want to conduct these substitutions :

```
(-((Cos[θ2] Cos[Φ] Sin[η2])/Sin[Φ]) == -Cos[ϕ2] Sin[θ2] - 
  Cos[η2] Cos[θ2] Sin[ϕ2]) /. {RègleCΦ, RègleSΦ}
```

The substitution doesn't work.

Can you help me to find a solution to conduct these substitutions?

A solution which keeps the same definitions of the rules would be great.

Note: when I obtained a ‘FullForm’ of the expression, I noticed that it contains some ‘Defer’ function. I wonder if my problem comes from this. But, I need to find a solution which allows me : 1) to prevent Mathematica from using secant and cosecant functions; and 2) to easily carry out substitutions in expressions or equations using rules.

Here the FullForm of the expression :

[image]

Comment: You should post the FullForm of the expression on which you are applying your rules, if you suspect that its form is part of the problem.  Also, it appears to me that the secant and cosecant rules have little to do with your current question.

Comment: Csc and Sec are the worst thing that happened to mathematica's analytical processing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7799/mathematica-sec-and-csc -- not to mention your own previous question, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76625/display-trigonometry-without-csc-and-cot -- Have you tried `SetSystemOptions[
 "SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False]` (from one of the answers to the first duplicate)?  It "works" for me.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your comment is very helpful and the tip you have advised me SetSystemOptions[ "SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False] is a solution which works for me ! I let you add the answer to my post. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

From [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101975/4999) by J.M.:

```
SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False];

(-((Cos[θ2] Cos[Φ] Sin[η2])/ Sin[Φ]) ==
   -Cos[ϕ2] Sin[θ2] - Cos[η2] Cos[θ2] Sin[ϕ2]) /. {RègleCΦ, RègleSΦ}
(*
  -((Cos[θ2] Sin[η2] (Cos[η2] Cos[θ2] Cos[ϕ2] - 
          Sin[θ2] Sin[ϕ2]) (Cos[η2] Cos[ψ2] + 
          Sin[η2] Sin[θ2] Sin[ψ2]))/(-Cos[ψ2] Sin[η2] Sin[θ2] + 
        Cos[η2] Sin[ψ2])) == -Cos[ϕ2] Sin[θ2] - Cos[η2] Cos[θ2] Sin[ϕ2]
*)
```

Comment: in fact, now the substitutions are conducted. But, it seems "SetSystemOptions["SimplificationOptions" -> "AutosimplifyTrigs" -> False];" doesn't prevent MAthematica to use Sec and Csc functions. Have you other ideas to both prevent these functions and permit substitutions with cos and sin expressions ?

Comment: I'm guess you mean that `Simplify[1/Sin[x]]` returns `Csc[x]` or even that entering `Csc[x]` does not immediately return `1/Sin[x]`.  These things are probably buried deep in code.  I often just write two rules, one for sin and one for csc, and so forth.

Comment: Exactly, it is what i mean. Can you write me the rules that you use? Thank you for you help.

Comment: @Bendesarts Something like `{Sin[whatever] -> expr, Csc[whatever] -> 1/expr}` etc.  Depends on the context.  Sometimes `{Sin -> s, Csc -> (1/s[#] &)}`, or `{_Sin -> s, _Csc -> 1/s}` if the arguments are all the same.  You can add assumptions like `s^2 + c^2 == 1` if `c` replaced `Cos[]`.