# Why doesn't FullSimplify return -x working on Abs[x] and x<0?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I am using Mathematica 11.1, and I stumbled upon this strange response using the `Abs` function.

```
FullSimplify[Abs[x],x<0]
(* Abs[x] *)
```

while, for example

```
FullSimplify[Abs[x],x>0]
(* x *)
```

as expected.

> **My question:** Why doesn't Mathematica simplify `Abs[x]` to `-x` when it is given the extra information `x<0`? Could it be on purpose?

I looked for duplicates, but I could not find a question that was spot on. I'm sorry if I missed some question.

Comment: according to help, `Abs[z] is left unevaluated if z is not a numeric quantity`  So really, both cases should be left unevaluated.  But looking at `Reduce[Abs[x] == x]` it says `Re[x] >= 0 && Im[x] == 0` so it seems like this is special case where `Abs[z]` is simplified to `z`. But help says it should be unevaluated if `z` is not numeric!

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for the comment. Does those "unevaluated" rules apply also when `FullSimplify` is applied? Maybe not. Always. It is still a bit confusing to me, if I per default have to count minus signs...

Comment: This example is discussed in the [Documentation for ComplexityFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) (see `> Scope` there).

Comment: Thank you for that link @Shadowray. This confirms it is _really_ by design.

Comment: fyi, Maple does this operation directly: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DEBTz.png)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Mathematica* considers `Times[-1,x]` to be a more complex expression than `Abs[x]`.

If you change the complexity function you can get the result you expect, e.g.

```
FullSimplify[Abs[x], x < 0, ComplexityFunction -> (Count[#, Abs, -1] &)]
(* -x *)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting. I'm a bit surprised that it then considers (for example)  the output $$\frac{1}{2-x}+\frac{1}{1+|x|}$$ to be simpler than $$\frac{3-2x}{2-3x+x^2}$$ when running `FullSimplify[1/(1 + Abs[x]) + 1/(1 + Abs[x - 1]), x < 0]`. If one changes to `0<x<1` or `x>1` as option instead, one gets rid of `Abs`. Appearantly, what is simpler for me is not simpler for Mathematica. Again, thank you! I will accept this answer unless someone will find a much more convincing answer in the next few days. In the meantime you have an upvote! Cheers!

Comment: @mickep Read [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html) under Properties & Relations. The system needs an objective measurement of complexity.  This link will give you the definition of complexity it uses by default, and will tell you how to define your own.

Comment: I guess the real question is why the expression is `Times[-1,x]` rather than just `Negate[x]` or something. It's not like the OP wrote `-1*x`...

Comment: @Mehrdad That seems like a reasonable optimisation to do. It doesn't seem useful to have `Negate` while there is already a more general construct that suffices, and that isn't that much more complicated.

Comment: @mickep For  related issues see this answer: [FullSimplify does not work on this expression with no unknowns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18869/fullsimplify-does-not-work-on-this-expression-with-no-unknowns/18875#18875).  It may appear to be version dependent.

Comment: @Artes Thank you, that is a bit mind blowing. I somehow accept that it is difficult to define what a `FullSimplify` command should return. In the case you link to and in the case in this question, I think it gives a non-optimal return. But all comments and the answer here has opened up my eyes that the problem is really to write a "perfect"  `FullSimplify` command, giving results considered easy by humans _and_ computer, yet being powerful. I will now accept the current answer, since that explains why the result is as it is.

Comment: @mickep: It's not even that it's hard, it's that it's not even a well-defined operation in the first place. Humans could easily disagree about the correct answer. For example, some might prefer $(x - 1)/(x + 1)$ to be simplified to $1 - 2/(x+1)$, and some might not...

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
Simplify[Abs[x /. x -> -y], x < 0 && y > 0 ]  /. y -> -x
```

Out:

```
-x
```