# Using Integrate and then Series seem to produce a wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, series-expansion

**Bug introduced in 11.1.0.0 or earlier and persisting through 14.0 or later**

---

Run this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
b[x_] := (a + e)^c[x];
v1 = Normal[Series[Integrate[b[x], x], {e, 0, 1}]]
v2 = Integrate[Normal[Series[b[x], {e, 0, 1}]], x]
```

to get this:

[image]

The first one is clearly wrong but the second one seems correct.

**What am I missing or this is a bug in Mathematica**?

I would not ask here but I need to perform some complicated transformations of integrals and this seems killing what I need to do. I am running **11.1.0.0** version of Mathematica. Does this work correctly in the most recent version?

Comment: I can't follow what you are trying to do. For a start, what would you expect the `Integrate[b[x], x]` expression to return?

Comment: Obviously, I expect `Integrate[b[x], x]` to return, well, `Integrate[b[x], x]`. The transformations above are "trivial" for a human. Mathematica seems to fail in a Taylor expansion there.

Comment: I think you should report this case to Wolfram

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch I did. See my comment below in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the same in V13. It looks like a bug to me. However, if I request order 11, I get order 1:

```
ClearAll[a, b, c, e, x];
b[x_] := (a + e)^c[x];
v1 = Normal[Series[Integrate[b[x], x], {e, 0, 11}]]
v2 = Integrate[Normal[Series[b[x], {e, 0, 1}]], x]
```

[image]

I do not understand why.

Comment: Yeah, it does look like a bug. Apparently 11 is a new 1 when doing a Taylor expansion over `Integrate`. Anything less than 11 results in not doing any Taylor expansion at all. 11 result in the first term, 12 in two terms and so on. Using 11 is a very unobvious workaround. I filed this as a bug with Wolfram.

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov Unsurprisingly, `Asymptotic[Integrate[b[x], x], {e, 0, 1}]` and `Asymptotic[Integrate[b[x], x], {e, 0, 11}]` behave like `Series`.

Comment: That's even more weird. Anyway, I went ahead with writing my own versions of `integrate`, `derivative` (instead of `D`), `simplify` and `series`. I need to do a mix of Taylor and variational calculus expansion at the same time and there seems to be nothing in Mathematica that can handle that nicely (not to mention the bug with `Integrate`).