# How can I collect the sum of any number of gradients without using ReplaceRepeated[]?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, design-patterns

Recently, I have run into the problem where I need to collect the the sum of  any number of  gradients. I have defined a function `grad[]` to represent the gradient, and a typical question is like:

how to collect

```
 grad[f]-grad[g]+grad[h]-grad[p]
```

into

```
grad[f-g+h-p]
```

Gradient can be collected this way since it is a linear operator. And so do other linear operators. I know I can write a binary rule and use `ReplaceRepeated[]` like:

```
grad[f]-grad[g]+grad[h]-grad[p]//.grad[a_]+grad[b_]:>grad[a+b]
```

But the problem is, I am not satisfied with the algorithm efficiency of  `ReplaceRepeated[]`. What I want is a patterned rule which does the trick with using `ReplaceAll[]` once rather than repeatedly.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Does `Distribute[grad[f]-grad[g]+grad[h]-grad[p] /. a_ * grad[x_] :> grad[ a * x ], grad]` solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks @BenIzd. Your code works if I decide to write an individual method or function called `CollectGradient[]`. However, what I want is a rule which can be used by `ReplaceAll[]` once, your code seems not quite applicable in this case for the reasons: 1. The pattern of expression needs recognizing before the expression can be manipulated. 2. If  your code is used as the r.h.s of the rule, there might appear nested replacement rules, I am not sure if that works.

Answer (score 2):

`linearCombine` from [Pushing Mathematica's FullSimplify to a global complexity minimum](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239422/pushing-mathematicas-fullsimplify-to-a-global-complexity-minimum/239568#239568) does the job:

```
ClearAll[linearCombine];
Module[{f}, SetAttributes[f, NumericFunction];
  constantQ = NumericQ[# /.
      s_Symbol /; MemberQ[Attributes[s], Constant] :> f[0]] &];
linearCombine[e_Plus, head_, constants_List : {}] := 
  Block[constants, SetAttributes[#, Constant] & /@ constants;
   head@Replace[e, {c_?constantQ*head[a_] :> c*a, head[a_] :> a}, 1] /;
     MatchQ[e, _[((_?constantQ)*_head | _head) ..]]];

linearCombine[grad[f] - grad[g] + grad[h] - grad[p], grad]

(*  grad[f - g + h - p]  *)
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I am really impressed by your ingenious  method. However, like I said to Ben in the comment under my original post, your code is very nice if I want to write an individual method or function doing this, but what I want is a patterned rule which can be used by ReplaceAll[] once, and your code might be too complicated for that purpose.

Comment: @AlbertLew `lcRule = DownValues@linearCombine` is such a rule. `constantQ` may be replaced by `NumericQ` if you don't want it to deal with symbolic constants.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I have tested the rule generated by `DownValues` and found that the expr has to be enclosed in `linearCombine[ ,grad]` then `ReplaceAll[]`  to make it work. Without the wrapper `linearCombine[ ,grad]` and letting `ReplaceAll[]` directly handle the expr like `grad[f] - grad[g] + grad[h]` with the rules won't work, which certainly leaves the way you suggested somewhat inconvenient since there are a lot of other rules which can directly be applied to the expr by `/.`. This specific rule regarding collecting `grad []` should be able to work together with them in a big rule List.

Answer (score 1):

You might try TagSet, something like this:

```
grad /: Times[-1, grad[x_]] := grad[-x]
grad /: Plus[ps___, grad[x_], qs___, grad[y_], rs___] := Plus[grad[x + y], ps, qs, rs]
```

The definition of Times might need to be extended depending on what sorts of expressions you expect to encounter. Also, some care might need to be taken to avoid nesting of `grad`. The definition for Plus might be overkill--I didn't do any real testing.

Comment: Thanks lericr. The TagSet method is an efficient and thorough way to define the form a particular pattern renders, and I do find it helpful to addressing my problem in terms of the form in which the operator applied to the product of a number and a symbol renders. For example, `grad /: grad[Times[n_?NumberQ,x_]] := n grad[x]`. But for the dealing of Plus, I do not think it is a good idea, since both the expanded form like `grad[f]+grad[g]-grad[h]` and collected form like `grad[f+g-h]` are needed, while once tag set is made, only one form can exist, with the other gone completely.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about your actual domain, so have a grain of salt at the ready... When you say that both forms are needed, that suggests different semantics. I like to indicate different semantics with different symbols. So, you could use the TagSet suggestion for one symbol, for illustration let's say `grad1` and your regular `grad` for the non-collected form. Then you can do your ReplaceAll but in a simpler way: `grad -> grad1`